# using python to do 3-D surface fitting

Tags: python, scipy

i can use module(scipy.optimize.least_squares) to do 1-D curve fitting(of course,i can also use curve_fit module directly) , like this

```
def f(par,data,obs):
    return par[0]*data+par[1]-obs
def get_f(x,a,b):
    return x*a+b
data = np.linspace(0, 50, 100)
obs = get_f(data,3.2,2.3) 
par = np.array([1.0, 1.0])
res_lsq = least_squares(f, par, args=(data, obs))
print res_lsq.x
```

i can get right fitting parameter (3.2,2.3),but when I generalize this method to multi-dimension,like this

```
def f(par,data,obs):
return par[0]*data[0,:]+par[1]*data[1,:]-obs
def get_f(x,a,b):
    return x[0]*a+b*x[1]

data = np.asarray((np.linspace(0, 50, 100),(np.linspace(0, 50, 100)) ) )
obs = get_f(data,1.,1.)

par = np.array([3.0, 5.0])
res_lsq = least_squares(f, par, args=(data, obs))
print res_lsq.x
```

I find i can not get right answer, i.e (1.,1.)，i have no idea whether i have made a mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you generate data and observations in the "multi-dimensional" case effectively results in `get_f` returning `(a+b)*x[0]` (input values `x[0]`, `x[1]` are always the same) and, similarly, `f` returning `(par[0]+par[1])*data[0]-obs`. Of course, with `a=1` and `b=1`, the exact same `obs` would be generated by any other values `a`, `b` such that `a+b=1`. Scipy correctly returns one of the (infinite) possible values satisfying this constraint, depending on the initial estimate.